# Kotlin: functional way to split list into grouped lists

Tags: kotlin, collections, functional-programming

I want to group specific items in a list based on a 'split predicate'. An example of what I mean:

```kotlin
val list = listOf("1", "2", "3", "", "4", "5", "6", "", "7")

// looking for: a nice readable (maybe functional?) way to get to:

val result = listOf(
  listOf("1", "2", "3"),
  listOf("4", "5", "6"),
  listOf("7"),
)
```

As you see, I want to split the list on items which are `item.isBlank()` - which I also want to drop in the process.

I know how to do it imperatively, but I think there must be a nice, readable, functional way!

Thanks a lot & regards

Marc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a solution that is similar to Matt's (had to run to a meeting and couldn't post it earlier!). It is materially the same, but allows you to specify an arbitrary predicate to split on, accounts for the fact that you might start with a blank item and end up with an unwanted empty list (or if you have two items that match the predicate in a row), and is defined as an extension function:

```
fun <T> List<T>.split(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<List<T>> =
    fold(mutableListOf(mutableListOf<T>())) { acc, t ->
        if (predicate(t)) acc.add(mutableListOf())
        else acc.last().add(t)
        acc
    }.filterNot { it.isEmpty() }
```

And to call it:

```
list.split { it.isBlank() }
```

// Returns [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a cleaner way but I think this solves it

```
list.fold (mutableListOf(mutableListOf<String>())) { acc, item ->
    if (item.isBlank()) {
        acc.add(mutableListOf())
    } else {
        acc.last().add(item)
    }
    acc
}
```